# Best CMS for news portal with external functionality

Tags: cms

What best CMS choose can be for information portal with extended functionality. I mean, basic functions like post news and ability to write add-on's for external website with new features like polls, gallery etc. But It need to be not like 2005's look for 500 users , need to make big high quality portal. What solutions exclude WordPress can be?

Comment: @JohnConde I realized a while ago that I needed to bookmark some answers for marking as duplicate. I just started with this one. Sorry- I was trying to solve a critical problem which I have and now I am updating my content (takes 24+ hours to run) or I would have dug deeper. Otherwise, I have been doing searches which are not as efficient. Is this how you keep track of dupes??

Comment: @closetnoc I just work by memory. When you see them often enough your spidey sense kicks in. Combined with a google search they're easy enough to find. `site:webmasters.stackexchange.com <search term>` surfaces dupes pretty quick.

Comment: @JohnConde Thanks for the tips... though my memory is bit suspect at my age. ;-) I tell people that senility starts early in my family- about 2pm.